# Wireless network not connecting to WiFi

Tags: wireless

All of a sudden my machine's wireless network is not connecting to my WiFi router.
How can I figure out if its an issue with the WLAN card or if its withing the Ubuntu system settings ?
Is there a command to check if the wireless is working ?

`$ nm-tool
NetworkManager Tool
State: disconnected
  Device: eth0
  Type: Wired
  Driver: e1000e
  State: unavailable
  Default: no
  HW Address: 00:1C:C0:34:D4:1F
  Capabilities:
     Carrier Detect: yes   Wired Properties
     Carrier: off`


`sudo lshw -C network
*-network
  description: Ethernet interface
  ....
  ....`

Comment: Yes, Broadcom STA wireless driver is activated. I haven't changed anything pertaining to IP config. Where to find that option? I couldn't find it. No, I did not dual boot it. Yes, wireless switch is 'on'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure Proprietary Drivers are enabled?

Are you sure you have not made any edits in the IP configs? Set it to "Automatic (DHCP)".

Do you have Windows installed? Does Wireless work in Windows?

Are you sure your hardware switch for the Wireless Card is turned on (this feature may not be present in some computers) ?